# Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array error occurred

Tags: java, eclipse

I have below code.

```
Complex[] time1Dummy = new Complex[time1.size()];
Complex[] freq1 = new Complex[time1.size()];
System.out.println("Size of time1:" +time1.size());

for(int i = 0; i < time1.size(); i++) {
    time1Dummy[i].setRe(time1.get(i));
    time1Dummy[i].setIm(0.00);
}
```

In this, Complex is the class which contains

```
private static Double re;   // the real part
private static Double im;   // the imaginary part`
```

Here, I am trying to assign values from array list time1 to complex value functions.

I am running this code in eclipse 4.3.2. Can someone please help me out in this?

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: Did you have a question????  (If you had an exception you should have included the *exact* and *complete* exception message *and* the stack trace.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is you are getting null pointer exceptions? See the first line I added within the for loop (assuming Complex has a default constructor).

```
Complex[] time1Dummy = new Complex[time1.size()];
Complex[] freq1 = new Complex[time1.size()];
System.out.println("Size of time1:" +time1.size());

for(int i = 0; i < time1.size(); i++) {
    time1Dummy[i] = new Complex();
    time1Dummy[i].setRe(time1.get(i));
    time1Dummy[i].setIm(0.00);
}
```

The first two lines of your code create arrays of Complex objects, but each element does not yet have an object created within it. You need to explicitly create an object first.

Also the attributes should not be static:

```
private Double re;   // the real part
private Double im;   // the imaginary part`
```

Comment: I think you are right in the fact that the arrays were empty before the loop was entered.

Comment: So Do I need to remove statement, Complex[] time1Dummy = new Complex[time1.size()];

Comment: yes, thats correct I have a default constructor for complex class

Comment: Also your attributes should not be static in your Complex class

Comment: Yep, having those values static means you really only ever have one Complex object, and all elements of the two arrays will contain exactly the same two values.  (This is assuming, of course, that there are elements in the two arrays in the first place.)

Comment: @Dinesh, you still need that statement to allocate the array.

Comment: @Dinesh, glad I could help, feel free to mark my answer as correct :)